# Websphere Data Source Test Connection failing with XAER_RMERR exception

Tags: oracle, websphere, datasource

We are trying to test data source connection on our Environment. 
We have Websphere v8.5.5 installed and Oracle 12c.

When we are using JDBC Driver ojdb7.jar, we are getting below exeption and test connection is failing  :

***0000007b XARminst      E   WTRN0037W: The transaction service encountered an error on an xa_recover operation. The resource was com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl@65d6afed. The error code was XAER_RMERR. The exception stack trace follows: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:730)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl.recover(WSRdbXaResourceImpl.java:1111)
        at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.XARminst.recover(XARminst.java:141)
        at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.XARecoveryData.recover(XARecoveryData.java:719)
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.PartnerLogTable.recover(PartnerLogTable.java:431)
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.resync(RecoveryManager.java:1534)
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.performResync(RecoveryManager.java:2267)
        at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RecoveryManager.performResync(RecoveryManager.java:117)
        at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.run(RecoveryManager.java:2220)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)***

One strange thing we noticed is when we are trying using ojdbc6.jar our test connection is successful, but the above exception is still there in logs.

So in conclusion with Oracle 12c installed Test connection is successful with ojdbc6.jar and not with ojdbc7.jar with above exception present in both cases.

Can someone help as we need to keep ojdbc7.jar as part of our requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

XAER_RMERR is generic error. Is data source XA?

Enable Oracle JDBC Driver trace and provide logs (including FFDC).

[How to enable Oracle JDBC Driver tracing with WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21598616)

**EDIT**: check out [Exception occurs during recovery of Oracle database transactions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21196663)

Answer (score 0):

Check the JDK version that WebSphere 8.5.5 is using.  Usually, WAS 8.5.5 will be using JDK 6 and hence, you should use ojdbc6.jar to be compatible with JDK6. Please be sure to change the JDK version before using ojdbc7.jar.

You can find the Java installed under WAS at the following location (/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The exception stack you pasted indicates that your application server was forced off or stopped abnormally while a transaction was in process. When this occurs, the resource used (db connection info) is recorded in the application servers partnerlogs and the transaction information in the tranlogs.  On subsequent application server restarts, the application server detects the unfinished transaction and attempts to reestablish the connection in the partnerlog and complete the transaction in the tranlog. There are configuration steps you must take in order for Oracle to allow this recovery OR if the lost transaction is of no concern, you can simply stop the application server, delete the partnerlogs and tranlogs and restart. - https://ibm.biz/BdEPuh